# how to use javascript variables for html input name in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 function f1(){
 document.getElementById("comment_show").innerHTML
 ="<form action='c.php' method='post'>a:"+
 "<input type='text' name='d1'> <br>"+
 "<textarea name='comment' rows='5' cols='100'> </textarea> <br>"+

 "b:"+
 "<input type='text' name='d2'> <br>"+
 "<textarea name='comment' rows='5' cols='100'> </textarea> <br>"+

 "c:"+
 "<input type='text' name='d3'> <br>"+
 "<textarea name='comment' rows='5' cols='100'> </textarea> <br>"+

 "<input type='submit' name='s1' value='s1'> <br><br><br><br>"+

 "</form>";
 }
```

How to replace d1,d2,d3 with javascript variables in order to make it as a loop?

Comment: `"mystring" + myVariable + "myOtherString"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would automate the creation of your inputs:

```
var inputsCount = 3;

var inputs = "";
var LETTER_START = "a".charCodeAt(0) - 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= inputsCount; i++) {
    inputs += String.fromCharCode(LETTER_START + i) + ":"+
    "<input type='text' name='d" + i + "'> <br>"+
    "<textarea name='comment' rows='5' cols='100'> </textarea> <br>";
}


var inner = "<form action='c.php' method='post'>" +
        inputs +
        "<input type='submit' name='s1' value='s1'> <br><br><br><br>" +
        "</form>";

document.getElementById("comment_show").innerHTML = inner;
```

Comment: I also have tired this before. But, it does not work so that I post it in stackoverflow. Now, I tried this method again and luckily this time, it works.
I don't figure out why it did not work yesterday. Anyway, it works. Thank you.

Comment: var d=1;

function add(){

d = d+1;

var temp2 = "<form action='c.php' method='post'> <font size='5pt'>";

for(var i = 1; i<=d ; i++){
temp2 = temp2+"d" + i + ":" + 
"<input type='text' name='d" + i + "'> <br>"+
"<textarea name='comment" + i + "'" rows='5' cols='100'> </textarea> <br>";
}

temp2 = temp2+"</font>"+"</form>";

document.getElementById("comment_show").innerHTML
= temp2;
}

this time, it doesn't work. Help!

Comment: I knew the problem. I missed out  " . It works again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to hold the names, then use jquery .each to generate the html string. Or you could just do a plain old for loop on the array.